# How to copy a folder, with exclusions, with native groovy?

Tags: groovy

This is easy enough to implement (will do it now unless someone answers real quick), but I'd always rather reuse than implement.

How can one recursively copy a folder in groovy, while excluding some folders/paths? I know this can be done with ant, but I think a simple native groovy code is nice to have as well.

Comment: So you want to avoid using [`AntBuilder`](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-using-antbuilder.html) too?  Example [here](http://www.codercorp.com/blog/groovy/groovy-file-magic-with-antbuilder.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting the code to use AntBuilder (Linked to from my comment above) in case [the page](http://www.codercorp.com/blog/groovy/groovy-file-magic-with-antbuilder.html) disappears at a later date:

```
new AntBuilder().copy(todir: "dstFolder") {
    fileset(dir : "srcFolder") {
        include(name:"**/*.java")
        exclude(name:"**/*Test.java")
    }
}
```

Not sure if you meant that for some reaon you wanted to avoid using Ant completely however...

Comment: I just hadn't integrated with Ant from Groovy yet, want a simple copy-paste function. Is the integration seemless? I'll copy-paste this and check.

Comment: It's definately been seamless since Groovy 1.6.5

Comment: Wow, too bad I can't upvote this 10 times. This is so much easier than I thought it would be - no need to link to anything, It Just Works TM. Here are a few extra links for those who might need them: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

Comment: What is the most interesting, is the behaviour of Eclipse+Groovy if you put that in the code. It doesn't require any includes - the reference is already included in some Groovy library, but the class needed is not in the list of reachable jars. You have an error for which there is no solution here on SO. (The type cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced) I killed 5 hours for your "solution"!To be useful, the answer has to say: What is the correct include for it? Where can I get the jar for it? As is, it works only on some installations - what was that yours?

Comment: I have no clue what you are banging on about...  Are you talking about the above answer? It just works in Groovy...  Try it in the Groovy Console.... I suspect your problem is Eclipse